# How do I change the background color of the <tr> that contains a certain link?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, background-color, tablerow

I want to change the background color of an "tr" element, that contains a given link.

My Snippet:

```
var color1 = "red";
var targetForum = $("tr a[href*='showforum=28']");

targetForum.each ( function () {
    var thisRow = $(this).parent ().parent ().parent ();        
    thisRow.style.backgroundColor = color1;
}
```

I tried rgb values as well as hex but nothing happens to the  bg color.

The target page looks like the following:

```
<tr>
    <td class="row2" align="center">
    <td class="row1" width="3%" align="center">
    <td class="row1">
    <td class="row1" width="15%">
        <span class="forumdesc">
            <a title="Off-Topic" href="showforum=41">ForumABC</a>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td class="row1" align="center">
    <td class="row2" align="center">
    <td class="row1" align="center">223460</td>
    <td class="row1">
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you have Firebug installed? It is very usefull to detect this kind of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Looks like you're using jQuery here, how is it loaded(by the forum or by GM)
2. When jQuery is loaded by the forum you must access jQuery using `unsafeWindow.$`
3. parent() returns an jQuery-Object, you cannot set the style-property of a jQuery-object using `obj.style`, use [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) instead

I would suggest this:(you don't need each)

```
unsafeWindow.$("tr:not(:has(tr)):has(a[href*='showforum=28'])").css('backgroundColor','red');
```

Comment: I know I'm missing **something**, but *why* `unsafewWindow.$`? Right now, I'm beginning to regret that last glass of wine... =/

Comment: Read this: **http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow** . If you like to access user-defined objects in the window/document(e.g. jQuery) you'll need to use unsafeWindow to point to the window-object. Native JS/DOM-objects are not affected by this restriction

Comment: But when jQuery is loaded by GM (**http://wiki.greasespot.net/Third-Party_Libraries**) you don't need to use unsafeWindow

Comment: Best not to recommend the use of `unsafeWindow` -- except in those few instances that call for using the target-page's JS (this isn't one of them).  Not only is it "unsafe", but it leads to scope/code confusion and introduces unnecessary dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Set the style the jQuery way (as was pointed out, `thisRow` is a jQuery object).
That would be: `thisRow.css ('backgroundColor', color1);`.

**However**, if the site uses a background image, the color may not appear to take effect. Use:

```
thisRow.css ('background', color1);
```

to make sure that any BG image doesn't mask the color change.

Finally, the site might style the BG of the table cells, which could, again, mask the row color-change.  To get around that, style the `<td>` elements as well.

So that would be:

```
targetForum.each ( function () {
    var thisRow = $(this).parent ().parent ().parent ();        
    thisRow.css ('background', color1);
    thisRow.find ("td").css ('background', color1);
}
```